# Problem in combining two plots when markers are used in the plot

Tags: plotting

I Have two plots with markers I wanted to combine the two plots using show but it is not happening, I have changed the plot range but still, I could not able to combine.

```
data1 = {{0.01, 1.8743}, {1., 1.8784}, {2., 1.88248}, {4., 

   1.89049}, {6., 1.89828}, {8., 1.90587}, {10., 1.91327}, {25., 
   1.96335}, {50., 2.03035}, {100., 2.12536}, {200., 2.23701}, {300., 
   2.30098}, {400., 2.34255}, {500., 2.37175}, {600., 2.3934}, {800., 
   2.42334}, {1000., 2.44307}, {2000., 2.48725}, {4000., 
   2.51208}, {5000., 2.5173}, {10000., 2.52799}, {15000., 
   2.53164}, {20000., 2.53348}, {30000., 2.53533}, {40000., 
   2.53625}, {70000., 2.53745}, {100000., 2.53793}, {1.*10^6, 
   2.53894}, {1.*10^8, 2.53909}, {1.*10^12, 2.53543}}
data2 = {{0.01, 4.69367}, {1., 4.69699}, {2., 4.70034}, {4., 
   4.70701}, {6., 4.71363}, {8., 4.72021}, {10., 4.72675}, {25., 
   4.77457}, {50., 4.84965}, {100., 4.98446}, {200., 5.20483}, {300., 
   5.37646}, {400., 5.51306}, {500., 5.62373}, {600., 5.71474}, {800.,
    5.85448}, {1000., 5.9557}, {2000., 6.20643}, {4000., 
   6.35701}, {5000., 6.38884}, {10000., 6.45382}, {15000., 
   6.47579}, {20000., 6.48682}, {30000., 6.49788}, {40000., 
   6.50342}, {70000., 6.51055}, {100000., 6.5134}, {1.*10^6, 
   6.51939}, {1.*10^8, 6.52013}, {1.*10^12, 6.52016}}
marker1 = {{Log@ks1[[5]], b1[[5]]}, {Log@ks1[[24]], b1[[24]]}};
marker2 = {{Log@ks1[[6]], b2[[6]]}, {Log@ks1[[25]], b2[[25]]}};
star = First[
   First[ImportString[
     ExportString[Style["\[SixPointedStar]", FontSize -> 16], "PDF"], 
     "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];
emptyhex = 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.1], Red}], White, star}, 
   ImageSize -> 20];
filledhex = Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Red, star}, ImageSize -> 20];

s1 = ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b1}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black, 
  Epilog -> {Inset[filledhex, marker1[[1]]], 
    Inset[emptyhex, marker1[[2]]]}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  PlotRange -> All]
s2 = ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b2}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black, 
  Epilog -> {Inset[filledhex, marker2[[1]]], 
    Inset[emptyhex, marker2[[2]]]}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  PlotRange -> All]
Show[s1, s2, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Comment: `ks1`,  `ks2`, `b1` and `b2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s1 = ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b1}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRange -> All]
s2 = ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b2}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}]
Show[s1, s2, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[filledhex, marker1[[1]]], Inset[emptyhex, marker1[[2]]], 
   Inset[filledhex, marker2[[1]]], Inset[emptyhex, marker2[[2]]]}]
```

[image]

**Note:**  In `Show` unspecified options are taken from the first argument. In your case, the value of the option `Epilog` from `s1` is used by `Show`.